# How to write/read hardware by ExtEscape in WDDM 2.0?

Tags: windows, driver, windows-driver

I want to use `ExtEscape` to read/write hardware info in application. `ExtEscape` is an API in <wingdi.h>.

What I want to know is that what can I do in KMD, and how to implement the function called by `ExtEscape` in KMD?

This is the function declaration of `ExtEscape`：

```
int ExtEscape(
    HDC hdc,
    int nEscape,
    int cbInput,
    LPCSTR lpszInData,
    int cbOutput,
    LPSTR lpszOutData
);
```

I don't want to do it by creating a new device and add private function.
I want to use `ExtEscape` if this route is right.